# SQL query not showing all results when using Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query that doesn't work on the server running `MySql`. All I want is for it to return a list of people and the number of times they appear in the table:

```
SELECT Person, Count(Person) as NoOfRecords FROM People;
```

This only returns one record and yet there are many. What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause

```
SELECT Person, Count(Person) as NoOfRecords FROM People GROUP BY Person;
```